# Limit records of data heart rate from google fit

Tags: google-fit

```
DataReadRequest.Builder()
             .read(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
             .enableServerQueries()
             .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
             .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
             .build()
```

I tried to get data for 2 months, but got the error:
onError -- 5022: Cannot bucket into more than 86400 intervals. -- null
If I transmit. SetLimit(1000) Then there will be data returned. What is the limit of the record limit API?

get all data 2 month